# Fatal error: Class 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine' - Symfony 2 Framework

Tags: symfony, composer-php, liipimaginebundle

I tried to implement liipbundle in symfony 2. But when I add this imagine_filter('thumbnail') into the image, it return an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine' not found in
>   /home/piripz8g/public_html/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php
>   on line 588

this is my code in the config file:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        thumbnail:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

routing:

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

appKernel:

```
    new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
```

twig:

```
{{ asset(f.path|imagine_filter('thumbnail')) }}
```

Comment: Clear the cache: `php app/console cache:clear -e prod`

Comment: i tried this command, but without success

Comment: Try running in development mode.  It's a bit confusing why you are even getting an error message in production mode since you usually will just get a white screen.  Unless you have debug turned on.  In any event, development mode should give you a better idea of what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add bundle to app/AppKernel.php

```
// ...
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...

            new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
        );

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The appKernel portion of the question strongly implies that he did.

Comment: It is not information where is this portion (may be it is written in dev or test environment only)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that php5-gd is not loaded. You can verify if php5-gd is loaded typing the following command:

```
$ php5 -m | grep -i gd
```

If is not loaded ...

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-gd
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```